# How to add an array to MEAN.JS on the client side

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mean-stack

I am trying to add an array of tasks to a project module on MEAN.js and I am using this question to follow up on how to add it to the server side ([How to add an array to a javascript server side model in MEAN.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34841778/how-to-add-an-array-to-a-javascript-server-side-model-in-mean-js), How to add an array to a javascript server side model in MEAN.JS) The answer given to me there only gets me to the point of inserting an empty array when entering data from the form on edit-project.client.view.html. So, I'll put the code here to check my client-side work, complete both these question and develop my profile. If there is any additional info required, besides the code I'll be adding, please leave suggestions to edit.

edit-project.client.view.html

```html
<section ng-controller="ProjectsController" ng-init="findOne()">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Edit Project</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <form name="projectForm" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="update(projectForm.$valid)" novalidate>
      <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group" show-errors>
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input name="title" type="text" ng-model="project.title" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" required>
          <div ng-messages="projectForm.title.$error" role="alert">
            <p class="help-block error-text" ng-message="required">Project title is required.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="description">Description</label>
          <textarea name="description" ng-model="project.description" id="description" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          Task Description
          <textarea name="description" ng.model="project.task.description" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="3" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
          <div>
            Task Status
            <input name="status" ng.model="project.task.status" class="form-control" placeholder="Status">  
          </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default">
        </div>
        
        <div ng-show="error" class="text-danger">
          <strong ng-bind="error"></strong>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

project.server.model.js

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

/**
 * Project Schema
 */
var ProjectSchema = new Schema({
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true,
    required: 'Title cannot be blank'
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true
  },
  /* MODEL for TASK ARRAY*/
  tasks: [{ 
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'Task' 
  }],
  
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});

mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);
```

projects.server.controller.js (partial - seems incomplete on server side)

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var path = require('path'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Project = mongoose.model('Project'),
  errorHandler = require(path.resolve('./modules/core/server/controllers/errors.server.controller'));

/**
 * Create a project
 */
exports.create = function (req, res) {
  var project = new Project(req.body);
  project.user = req.user;

  project.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.json(project);
    }
  });
};

/**
 * Show the current project
 */
exports.read = function (req, res) {
  res.json(req.project);
};

/**
 * Update a project
 */
exports.update = function (req, res) {
  var project = req.project;

  project.title = req.body.title;
  project.description = req.body.description;

  project.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.json(project);
    }
  });
};
...
```

Comment: You posted same code and question as your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34841778/how-to-add-an-array-to-a-javascript-server-side-model-in-mean-js.

Comment: You could have asked followup questions in the comments of your previous question. But this is duplicate.

Comment: I can change it then, but how? The first question is about client-side code, which will have to do with angular and the server side has to do with mongoose.

Comment: Should it just be one question... How do I add an array to a meanJS module? If not, I wrote the second question to complete my first and give credit to the guy that gave me an answer. If I change it I can't give credit to the person that answered my first question... and that' the only question anyone has answered on stack for me thus far.